# Postgres Database lookup table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database that in simple terms has **Addresses**, **Buildings**, **Listings** they are all linked together a building has an address, a listing has a building. The issue starts because there are multiple sources that the data comes from that use different id sequences and I have to keep track of the sources id for deleting and editing the data.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses
(
 "id"            serial NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE buildings
(
 "id"              serial NOT NULL,
 address_id      serial NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE listings
(
 "id"              serial NOT NULL,
 building_id     serial NOT NULL,
);
```

Example of the source ids

```
Source1: 24164454
Source2: 36uLTN8oq8JMV2Pg7fXaX0
Source3: 14524298
```

Obviously the way its setup now it couldn't handle source2's ids. The issue I am facing is I cant just set it to the sources id because for example source 1 and 3 could collide with their id structure.

My question then what is the best way to solve this? Lookup table? have source and source id as composite keys (this feels messy)

Comment: Create fields `id_source varchar` that contains source data e.g `'source1', 'source2', etc` and `source_value varchar` that contains the actual id value. You would probably want `id_source` to be a Foreign Key to source table that contains more information about the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem quite reasonable to have a column **source_id** and then an **id** column which will be type INT, the PRIMARY KEY and  SERIAL.
If your id's are coming from different sources it is quite possible that you will have duplicates with the same number coming from different sources. For this reason I would advise against using it as an id and against making the column unique.
I had this problem in a company which used the suppliers references as their references which was all very simple until we realised that we had a lot of duplicates.

Comment: A very basic takeaway here: If you cannot control the value of a data point/column you cannot use it as a PK.